# Sending accented characters to Clipboard from a batch file

Tags: windows, batch, clipboard, special-characters

I've been trying to find a solution to this, but I wrote a basic program to automatically produce an "outage" report more or less, that I need copied into the clipboard so that I can paste it into a mainframe system. It needs to be in English and French, but the French accents are not copying properly... Is there anyway around this - to include the variables?

The output will basically be this `le syst├¿me ne`  (clipped out the rest).

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

This is that I have so far:

```
if "%SRSST%"=="n" (
    (
    echo                   ***  IMSNEWS ***
    echo.
    echo On Sunday, %DATEME% %DT%%DATEST% %DATEYR%, There will be no
    echo system outage.
) | Clip )else (
            echo                   ***  IMSNEWS ***
            echo.
            echo On Sunday, %DATEME% %DT%%DATEST% %DATEYR%, the system will not
            echo be available between %SRSST% - %SRSET% for regular
            echo weekly maintenance.
        ) | Clip
timeout /t 5
if "%SRSST%"=="n" (
    (
    echo                  ***  NOUVELLES ***
    echo.
    echo Le dimanche %DT% %DATEME%, %DATEYR%,  Il n'y aura pas
    echo d'interruption du système 
) | Clip )else (
            echo                  ***  NOUVELLES ***
            echo.
            echo Le dimanche %DT% %DATEME%, %DATEYR%, le système ne
            echo sera pas disponible entre %SRSST% - %SRSET% pour la
            echo maintenance hebdomadaire.
        ) | Clip

goto Menu
```

Comment: "and the French accents are copying properly"  If they're copying properly, then what's the problem exactly? Or was that a typo?

Comment: They are not copying properly at all > it's showing `syst├¿me ne` instead of `système` - as an example (in notepad)

Comment: Seems to work fine here... Perhaps the target (the "mainframe system") you're pasting into is the problem... If you paste what it puts onto the clipboard into Notepad, does it display properly?

Comment: Sorry - just to be clear, when the output is pasted into notepad (or any other system) the character "è" looks like "├¿"

Comment: Well that's weird, like I said it works fine here (Windows 7 English).  Which version of Windows are you using?  What install language is it (English, French, or ???)?

Comment: If you open a command prompt and run `chcp`, which code page is reported?

Comment: Using windows 7 as well - in English. but if it works for you, perhaps I'm having a windows issue... I'll have to test it on another pc

Comment: Active code page: 437

Comment: Yup, that's the code page I would expect.  Yeah that's just weird. :)  Like I said it works fine here: [image](http://i.imgur.com/Hg6rgrf.jpg)

Comment: Yep.. so I tested that typing directly from cmd prompt, and it does in fact work. but not from the batch file itself....

Comment: `chcp 1252` fixes the problem. Answer added.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Works from the command line but not in a batch file. Changing the code page in the batch file fixes it (I'm not sure why exactly)

Comment: The example picture I stick in my comment is a shot of it being run from a batch file.. Weird..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation the issue was strange - Using `chcp 1252` In a test.cmd - would work.... but for some reason would not work in me larger batch file. (I have honestly no idea why as I copied the text code for code

```
:TST
@echo off
cls
chcp 1252
echo d'interruption du système | CLIP
pause
goto Menu
```

However I found that adding the line `chcp 65001` Worked for everything.

```
:TST
@echo off
cls
chcp 65001
echo d'interruption du système | CLIP
pause
goto Menu
```

Hopes this helps out.

Comment: Thank you for this!

Answer (score 1):

#### The French accents are not copying properly

Add `chcp 1252` (West European Latin) to the start of the batch file.

- Without this I can reproduce your problem (my default code page is 850 - Multilingual (Latin I)
- With it added I get the expected text on the clipboard.

Example 1:

```
F:\test>type test.cmd
echo systÞme | Clip
F:\test>test

F:\test>echo systÞme   | Clip

F:\test>systÞme
'systÞme' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Example 2:

```
F:\test>type test.cmd
chcp 1252
echo systÞme | Clip
F:\test>test

F:\test>chcp 1252
Active code page: 1252

F:\test>echo système   | Clip

F:\test>système
'système' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Notes:

- In the above tests I just pasted the contents of the clipboard onto the command line.
- Without the `chcp` the clipboard contained `systÞme`.
- With `chcp` the clipboard contained `système`.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [chcp](http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html) - Change the active console Code Page. The default code page is determined by the Windows Locale.

Comment: I have to laugh - Yes this works. In a simple batch file..  Thank you  much for this... (but for some reason it does not work as part of the total batch file...) but there's some bug probably somewhere. Thanks for the help

Comment: You're welcome ;) I still don't know **why** it is needed though.